# I am trying to simulate else in mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Delete .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# If file does not exist redirect to error.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ error.php [L]

# Friendly URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user.php?ID=$1 [L]
```

**Problem:** The second statement works by Itself but when I add the first statement the second always redirects me to error.php.

**Possible solution:** I thought about doing something like this:

```
if(RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ error.php [L]
else
    RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user.php?ID=$1 [L]
```

I have been a while trying to figure out by myself how to make It work but I can't. A would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Friendly URL for user/...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user.php?ID=$1 [L,QSA,NC] 

# Add .php extension internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# If there is no rewrite and 
# files/directory don't exist then forward to error.php
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ""
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . error.php [L]
```

Comment: If I add "API" (the name of my folder) after the DOCUMENT_ROOT It works, also I didn't know about "%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}". Thanks man!